# Compatibility View settings inside IE9 to Edge

Tags: internet-explorer, compatibility

I have IE9 browser on windows 7.
The browser doesn't shows scrollers on the page correctly.
If I add this setting to header:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Then it works. This is from documentation:
"Compatibility View function allows users to "revert" to a previous browser version."

Since IE9 doesn't know what is edge, it probably goes to some default state and it should be the same if I add x instead of edge:

But if I write x, page doesn't work any more. So, how can edge influence the old IE9 inside old operation system since it has no clue, what edge is?
Can someone explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `"IE=edge"` notation is used in IE to the browser to use the best available rendering mode. This basically means that IE8 will be forced to use IE8 mode, IE9 will be forced to use IE9 mode, IE10 will use IE10 mode, and IE11 will use IE11 mode.

The purpose of this flag is to override anything else (such as local browser config settings) that might be telling IE to go into an older compatibility mode instead of it's normal mode.

The word "edge" is a specific keyword that triggers this functionality; you can't replace it with anything else and get the same results.

"Edge" in this context is a reference to "the cutting edge", ie the most advanced version.

Please note: This usage of the word "Edge" is entirely unrelated to the name that Microsoft have given their new Edge browser.

Answer (score 0):

I too had this compatibility problem in ie9. The site was developed in Drupal 7. So i add a html code in the head section of `html.tpl.php` file in the templates folder.When you add this tag, it should be added just below the  tag of your html page.

Html code :-

```html
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EDGE"/>
```